# Adding layer to story map?

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, story-map

I am trying to add a trail line to a story map. I can not find where in the story map it allows for adding a layer.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Which Story Map template are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, layers are added into the web map and then shared as an app/story map.

It will be helpful if you can you provide a more information on which story map you are trying to use.